# GPIO output high not turning of relay

Tags: gpio, relay

I am trying to turn a relay on and off using a python script.
The below script is realy simpel, turn the relay on and after 5 seconds turn it off.

The thing is, it dooesn't turn off. i thought it did because i had the cleanup() in there. But no...

It is probably something realy dumd that i am forgetting.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(26, GPIO.OUT)

GPIO.output(27, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(26, GPIO.LOW)

time.sleep(5)

GPIO.output(27, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(26, GPIO.HIGH)

print("wegwgwegweg")

time.sleep(10)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

The relay bnoard that i am using is:
https://www.kiwi-electronics.nl/nl/16-kanaals-5v-relais-module-4322
[image: 16CH relay board]

Note that i am only using 3 relay's currently to limit the power usage of the 5v line on the PI

Comment: Relays are usually active-low, so turn the pin low to deactivate.

Comment: The `GPIO.LOW` Turns the relay on. How would you suggest doing it?

Comment: You have the wrong relay.  It probably needs 5V logic to operate.

Comment: You should know that there are many different types of relays and electrical specifications. With no information on ***which*** relay you're using, it will be very difficult for anyone here to help you much. Please **edit your question**,  add some details on your relay, and perhaps describe what it is you're trying to accomplish. This is not a difficult question if you can provide a few details.

Comment: Sorry I meant turn the pin high to deactivate. The logic would be the opposite to what you'd expect.

Comment: Ah, "***Rpi cannot turn relay off***" is top of Rpi relay newbie sorrows. ***Appendix B*** of my TLDR answer to this EE Q&A might help: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/505318/how-to-properly-use-a-relay-module-with-jd-vcc-from-arduino-raspberry/508672#508672.

Comment: Reading the Appendix B part of @tlfong01 i started measuring the voltage.
And you said for low level's it is not supposed to be higher then 0,8v well well , i have 0,13v.
That might be an issue.
When it's HIGH the voltage is 3,25V, wich is also not the correct voltage.
I am gonna try to hook up an external power supply later today to check if that's fixes the issue.

Comment: Yes, you got it. 3.25V of course is not high enough to switch off your relay which was very likely designed for 5V Arduino whose High is above 4V.